# Description: HTTP 404 for JSON return

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, rest

i'm kinda new to programming c# and asp.net, i just want to build a rest api for my android app to sign in and sign up. but i face a problem for sign in (login).
the problem is i just wrote this codes below:

```
namespace CPanel.Controllers
{
    public class DashboardController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Dashboard
        public ActionResult CreateUser()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateUser(string username,string password)
        {
            CPanel.Models.CPanelEntities1 db = new Models.CPanelEntities1();
            db.USP_AddUSer(username, password);
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult login(string username,string password)
        {
            CPanel.Models.CPanelEntities1 db = new Models.CPanelEntities1();
            try
            {
                var user = db.USP_Authenticate(username, password).First();
                return Json(new { UserId = user.UserId,Username=user.Username,IsAdmin=user.IsAdmin,Message="ok"});
            }catch(Exception)
            {
                return Json(new { message = "error" });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the first part (CreateUser) work perfectly. but second part (login) only work on "Postman" chrome application.
i post a request on "Postman" -

> localhost/dashboard/login?username=php&password=php

and i see a json:

> {
>    "UserId": 29,
>    "Username": "php",
>    "IsAdmin": false,
>    "Message": "ok"
>   }

in localhost and wwwroot (iis) there in no chance and i face this error:

> **Server Error in '/' Application.**
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /dashboard/login
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1586.0

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by _"in localhost and wwwroot (iis) there in no chance"_? Did you try to access the url from a web browser and it didn't work?

Comment: Well he can't find the URL you are specifying. Are you sure you want to have a slash before dashboard? Are you starting in the root folder?

Comment: i think there is nothing wrong with url because i pass the url in "Postman" as i said ,and get the json i wanted.

Comment: @botond.botos yes i type the url in web browser but error happened. the same url worked in "Postman".

Comment: @PedramHassas, when you enter the url to a web browser it issues a GET request, but your controller expects POST.

Answer (score 2):

When you enter the `http://localhost/dashboard/login?username=php&password=php` url to web browser it issues a GET request, however your controller only accepts POST requests.

There's another thing, as far as I understand you need a web api but your example is a standard ASP.NET MVC controller. You might want to take a look on the following tutorial: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api